# Hide the field "name" in BuddyPress at registration

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress, multisite

I am using wordpress multisite and I want to hide the field name at the registration. The following code might work on single site but definitely does not work on multisite. How can we make it work on Multisite?

In your CSS:

```
div.field_1{
    display:none;
}
```

In your bp-custom.php or functions.php:

```
function buddydev_disable_firstname() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            var jq=jQuery;

            jq("#signup_username").on("blur",function(){

                jq("#field_1").val(jq("#signup_username").val());

            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'bp_after_register_page', 'buddydev_disable_firstname');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into *wp-login.php* source, you'll see that Wordpress make a special redirection for multisite installations:

```
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    wp_redirect( apply_filters( 'wp_signup_location', network_site_url( 'wp-signup.php' ) ) );
    exit;
}
```

So if you look in that file, you'll see that the user name is display in this way:

```
echo '<input name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" value="'. esc_attr($user_name) .'" maxlength="60" /><br />';
```

Then to hide the field + the label, you need to write:

```
label[for="user_name"], input[name="user_name"] {
    display: none;
}
```